# Как получить по клику на Autocomplete с React Material Ui обьект?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete](http://AutoComplate)

Есть Autocomplete:

```
<AutoComplete
  fullWidth={true}
  name='contractorName'
  dataSourceConfig={{ text: 'name', value: 'id' }}
  dataSource={::this.renderContractorsList()}
  onUpdateInput={::this.handleContractorName}
  onBlur={e => console.log(e.target)}
/>
```

dataSource:

```
renderContractorsList() {
    const { contractorsList } = this.props;

    return contractorsList.map(contractor => {
        return { name: contractor.name, id: contractor.id };
    });
}
```

Как по клику на выпадающее меню получить соответсвующий `{ name: contractor.name, id: contractor.id }` ?

Comment: Вам на такой вопрос здесь вряд ли ответят. Потому что ни исходников вашего компонента Autocomplete ни ссылки на гитхаб Вы не привели.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму это компонент из библиотеки material ui http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete

Comment: По беглому взгляду на документацию я думаю что вам нужен обработчик onNewRequest вторым параметром которого будет индекс и по индексу найти в датасорсе нужный элемент

Answer (score 1):

```
<AutoComplete
  fullWidth={true}
  name='contractorName'
  dataSourceConfig={{ text: 'name', value: 'id' }}
  dataSource={::this.getContractorsList()}
  onUpdateInput={::this.handleContractorName}
  onNewRequest={::this.onContractorItemClick}
/>
```

Добавить свойтво `onNewRequest={::this.onContractorItemClick}`

```
onContractorItemClick(contractor) {
  const { id: contractorId } = contractor;

  this.setState({ contractorId });
}
```